# How to Filter Datatable using multiple condtions

Tags: vb.net, datatable, rowfilter

Hi I am trying to filter a datagrid using datatable.DefaultView.RowFilter but i need to filter using multiple conditions.

I have tried something like:

```
Dim dt as DataTable
Dim carrier As String = txtCarrier.Text.ToUpper
Dim customer As String = txtCustomer.Text.ToUpper
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "[Client] LIKE '*" & _
       customer & "*' OR [Carrier] LIKE '*" & carrier & "*'"
```

any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Did you load the DataTable variable before?

Comment: test if either textbox IsNullOrEmpty then build the query from the one that is not empty. the SQL is more like `Client LIKE '" & search & "%'"`